# How to print only the max value of an ouput

Tags: python, printing, python-requests, set, max

I have seen numerous posts on this topic, but none have worked for me. For this reason I am asking my own question specific to what I am trying to do. The code I have set up is below.

```
def get_assets_for_group(ip):
    decom_match = str(ip)
    url5 = server + path1
    response = requests.request("GET", url5, headers=headers, verify=False)
    data = response.json()
    for i in data['resources']: 
        url = server+path2+str(i)
        response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, verify=False)
        data = response.json()
        if decom_match in data["ip"]:
            d = {i}
            max_value = max(d)
            print("Match found!", max_value)
```

The output of this code will give me all the matching values when I only want it to return the one with the highest number. An example of the output is below.

```
Match found! 111618
Match found! 112367
Match found! 115401
Match found! 115618
Match found! 116265
Match found! 116400
Match found! 117653
```

Am I using the max function wrong? Please let me know what you think or possible fixes.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: I think it is printing multiple matches because the for loop it is in keeps running. Maybe break out of the loop after the first match is found?

Comment: @OlvinRoght i just want to print the highest number in d= {i} rather than all of them like the output i provided above.

Comment: @MarcusWeinberger i cant have it break the loop because i need the script to find all the matches and print the one with the highest number which in this example is '117653'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you are applying the `max()` function on a set containing only `i` - and then printing the result - every time you find a matching value. One way to rectify this is to create an initial set, `matches`, and then every time you find a match, add it to that set. After you've finished searching the response for matches, you can then use `max()` on this set and print the result.

Something like this:

```
def get_assets_for_group(ip):
    decom_match = str(ip)
    url5 = server + path1
    response = requests.request("GET", url5, headers=headers, verify=False)
    data = response.json()

    matches = set()

    for i in data['resources']: 
        url = server+path2+str(i)
        response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, verify=False)
        data = response.json()
        if decom_match in data["ip"]:
            matches.add(i)

    if matches:
        print("Match found!", max(matches))
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of problems in your code. You iterate over your data, create a new set in each iteration and apply the max function of this new set with only one entry, therefore it is always the one entry, that is in your set. You should either fill the set with all found matches and apply the `max()` function afterwards, or check in every iteration, if a new max value has been found:

```
    max_value = None
    for i in data['resources']: 
        url = server+path2+str(i)
        response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, verify=False)
        data = response.json()
        if decom_match in data["ip"]:
            if max_value == None:
                max_value = i
            else:
                max_value = max(i, max_value)
    if max_value != None:
        print("Match found!", max_value)
    return max_value
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell what you're doing without example data but it looks like you're running `max` on a single value every time in the loop.

Define a variable outside the loops containing the maximum found value and check inside the loop if the current value is higher like so:

```
def get_assets_for_group(ip):
    decom_match = str(ip)
    url5 = server + path1
    response = requests.request("GET", url5, headers=headers, verify=False)
    data = response.json()

    max_value = 0 # initialize max value
    for i in data['resources']: 
        url = server+path2+str(i)
        response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, verify=False)
        data = response.json()
        if decom_match in data["ip"]:
            d = {i}
        # check if value is higher than last found value
        if (d > max_value):
            max_value = d

    print("Match found!", max_value)
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it a matter of calculating the max after your for loop finished perhaps? Also put all values in a list first.

```
...
d=[]
    for i in data['resources']: 
        url = server+path2+str(i)
        response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, verify=False)
        data = response.json()
        if decom_match in data["ip"]:
            d.append(i)

max_value = max(d)
print("Match found!", max_value)
```